# .csv value delimiter that works with any Regional Settings in both Microsoft Excel and Google Docs

Tags: excel, csv, google-docs

In a web app, the user should be able to export his data in .csv format which should be compatible with both MS Excel and Google Docs.

A naive solution is to create the .csv file by separating data rows with `/r/n`, values with commas, and wrap them in double quotes (to handle special characters). This won't always work. Turns out Excel uses the user's Regional format to determine the appropriate data separator, and for some regions (e.g. most of Europe, where the comma is used as the decimal separator), a semicolon should be used instead of a comma. These users would get all comma-separated values rendered in a single row.

The second solution is to separate the values with a semicolon instead. This however breaks it for regions where the comma should be the default separator (e.g. UK and US).

The third solution is to define the separator explicitly by placing e.g. `sep=,` at the top of the file. This solves the problem for users with any Regional Settings, but only in MS Excel. Google Docs does not know about `sep=,` and renders it as yet another row.

I also stumbled upon very old solutions that suggest writing `sep` as a comment (e.g. `# sep=,`) or placing it on the second row (after the headers). Neither of these seems to work with the new versions of MS Excel.

And another potential solution I thought of is to detect user's Regional Settings (decimal separator to be precise) from within the web application and generate the file that would work on this user's machine (which isn't ideal). Seems like HTTP Accept-Language attribute would be the way to go, but it feels like a very overcomplicated solution for such a task.

So, my question would be:

**Is there a way to format a .csv file, such that it reads properly in MS Excel with any Regional Settings (e.g. both Germany and US), that also does not render an extra `sep` row in Google Docs?**

Comment: Users that have to open an incompatible .csv file in MS Excel are able to *Import* it, which allows them to select the delimiter. I think this would be the final solution if I can't find a better solution.
I'm wondering though wether there is an approach that "just works" for the user.

Comment: Use `|` as separator.

Comment: I believe your comment about ***importing*** csv file for Excel users is best. There are issues not only with list separator, decimal separator, and thousands separator, but also with date formatting (MDY vs DMY). Although, depending on your control over the data, you could store all the dates in an unambiguous format (eg YMD).